# Disable sorting for last row

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have the last row in an ag grid that needs to be always the last, even after sorting by any column. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, found it by myself :)

```
gridOptions.postSort = (rowNodes) => {
   for(let x in rowNodes) 
       rowNodes[x].data.lastRow&&rowNodes.push(rowNodes.splice(x,1)[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice approach here would be to use the `pinned row` feature provided by [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) itself.

> Pinned rows appear either above or below the normal rows of a table. This feature in other grids is also known as Frozen Rows or Pinned Rows.

```
this.gridApi.setPinnedBottomRowData(rows);
```

Have a look at this example provided by them: [ag-grid - Row Pinning](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-pinning/#example-row-pinning)

Comment: but pinned row will stay in one place even when you scroll

Comment: Oh... I see ur req now.. anyways will keep this ans, somebody will surely get help from this.